# VBA Insert row at bottom of table and Copy formula directly from above

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table and in column A, the formula is the "cell above + 1", so `A15 =$A14 + 1`. In column B, I compiled all tabs into "SheetName" so they can be referenced using the value in column A, and then made into a hypyerlink.

`A15 =HYPERLINK("#'"&INDEX(SheetNames,$A15)&"'!A1",INDEX(SheetNames,$A15))`
I want a VBA to insert a row at the bottom of the table and copy the formulas from above for the entire row (which in my spreadsheet is from A to Z.)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("SUMMARY")

    Dim newrow As ListRow
    Set newrow = tbl.ListRows.Add
    With newrow
        .Cells(1).EntireRow.Copy
        .Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlShiftUp, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

The error I get is "Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method". Also, only column A formula was copied down. Column B didn't copy, column C says "#REF!" and the other columns didn't copy at all.

Comment: `ListRow` doesn't have an `Offset` property, untested but `.Range.Offset` I would think.

Comment: Where does that go?

Comment: Change the `.Offset(1)` to `.Range.Offset(1)`

Comment: Did that - still get the exact same output. Column A copies but B-Z don't.

Comment: Side note - `xlShiftUp` is not valid for `Range.Insert`. The only options are `xlShiftToRight` or `xlShiftDown`

Comment: Does the table span columns A to Z, or which columns is it in?

Comment: my table is exactly from A to Z

Comment: Try `.Formula = .Range.Offset(-1).Formula` (again, untested)

Comment: `ListRow` doesn't have a `Cells` property either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, `ListRow` doesn't have a `Cells` or `Offset` method. The following will add the formulas from the previous row to the newly added row:

```
With newrow.Range
    .Formula = .Offset(-1).Formula
End With
```

though there is an option in Excel to do this automatically, which is why I'm confused as to your purpose here.

[image]

**EDIT:**

Perhaps the following is better:

```
With newRow.Range
    .Offset(-1).Copy
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With
```

Comment: This worked! However, like in column A, the new cell should be ```A16 =$A15 + 1```, but it kept $A14+1

Comment: @DeAnnaMartinez - you know there is an option to do this automatically right?

Comment: what do you mean "automatically"? I know I can use "ctrl + D" to copy cells above - but I'm passing this sheet onto people who don't want to have to use formulas. So creating a button was what I resorted to.

Comment: File > Options > Proofing > AutoCorrect Options > Fill Formulas in tables to create calculated columns.